# Playwright consistently captures a 404 request code despite the successful loading of the product on Target(retailer website)

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright, target, scrapy-playwright

I aim to scrape products from Target, utilizing Scrapy, which has proven effective for retailers like Amazon and Walmart. However, I am encountering a challenge with Target. Despite the product page loading successfully, the Target website responds with a status code 404.

Investigation in the browser's Inspection -> Network tab also reveals a 404 status.

I attempted to use Scrapy Playwright to load the website in a browser and then scrape, but the issue persists.

For a clearer understanding, please refer to this brief video: [Issue Link](https://www.loom.com/share/7c5f2c520a8d4262ab76a564b0c74389?sid=6b5d57b9-874c-4382-9a56-3e6b437e0633)

Here is the code I used.

```
import datetime
import re
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from .base_redis_spider import BaseRedisSpider
from ..enums.globals import RETAILERS, Component


class TargetSearchProductSpider(BaseRedisSpider):
    custom_settings = {'ITEM_PIPELINES': {"scrapers.pipelines.timestamp_pipeline.TimeStampPipeline": 400,
                                          "scrapers.pipelines.redis_item_store_pipeline.RedisItemStoragePipeline": 501, },
                       # add timestamp to item
                       "DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS": {"http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
                                             "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler", },
                       "PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSER_TYPE": "firefox", "HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES": [404],
                       "PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS": {"headless": False}

                       }
    name = "target"

    def generate_key(self):
        return f"{self.retailer.lower()}_{self.component.lower()}_{self.environment.lower()}"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TargetSearchProductSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.retailer = RETAILERS.TARGET
        self.environment = kwargs.get('environment').upper()
        self.component = kwargs.get('component').upper()
        self.spider_key = self.generate_key()  # 'target_retail_production'

        self.redis_key = f"{self.spider_key}:start_urls"
        self.redis_batch_size = 1  # Number of url to fetch from redis on each attempt
        self.max_idle_time = 60  # Max idle time(in seconds) before the spider stops checking redis and shuts down

    def modify_request(self, request):
        return request.replace(meta={'playwright': True, 'playwright_include_page': True}, callback=self.parse,
                               errback=self.errback)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        # Get the Playwright browser instance from the response.meta dictionary
        browser = response.meta['playwright_browser']
        # ...other logic ...
        await self.close_browser(browser)
        yield {}

    async def errback(self, failure):
        self.logger.error(repr(failure))
        # Get the Playwright browser instance from the response.meta dictionary
        browser = failure.request.meta['playwright_browser']
        # Close the browser
        await browser.close()
```